# Free Linux video program with special YouTuber effects

Tags: gratis, linux, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a program that's free for Linux and that can edit videos with special effects like in this video:

https://youtu.be/i-Cbm9ECC0Y

Every video has a special intro with a theme relevant to the channel, multimedia-text overlays in the video, split screens, thumbnails in credits, etc.. I'm stuck with Windows Movie Maker and I don't know what to use. I have no money to buy anything fancy, but neither do I want to download something pirated.

As always, Linux had free software for whatnots. Does anyone know of a video program?

Comment: Please describe the effects used in the video, people should not have to click on a link to see what you mean. Meanwhile I put your question on hold, but we will reopen it as soon as it gets better :-) Include screenshots if necessary, but also describe with text a bit more, this will make the question more findable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility which fits your requirements is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) - the 3-D modelling package which now includes a comprehensive video editing suite.

Features relating to your requirements:

- Linux - **Yes** & Windows & OS-X
- Free - **Yes** both gratis & Open Source
- Pirated - **No** you can download completely legally

Some things you didn't ask for:

- 3D Effects - of course you can even make your video fly in!
- Support multiple video file formats - AVI, MPEG and Quicktime (on OSX).
- Live preview, luma waveform, chroma vectorscope and histogram displays
- Audio mixing, syncing, scrubbing and waveform visualization
- Up to 32 slots for adding video, images, audio, scenes, masks and effects
- Speed control, adjustment layers, transitions, keyframes, filters and more.
- If you are regularly doing the same sort of thing you can even script operations.
- Takes your copyright - **No** some packages and many on-line tools take copyright off of you.

Some tutorials can be found on [you-tube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20video%20editing%20tutorial) with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw-Hjc496ng) one a good intro into adding titles to videos

### The Video Editor Pane

[image: Video Editor Pane]